# Python variation of TSP with optimization

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, optimization, path-finding

community,

I am a beginner in the field of pathfinding, in Python I am trying to create an algorithm for an undirected weighted graph which when inputted an unordered list of nodes would return an ordered list that would have the lowest distance. This variation of TSP however is different in two things.

1. Salesman can start at any node
2. Salesman doesn't need to end in the startin node

I am trying to achieve this using the Ant-Colony-Optimization, here is a code which I am using:
[Github page](https://github.com/Vampboy/Ant-Colony-Optimization/blob/master/AntColony_python3_code.py). How would I implement these changes into the code, so that if I input `[cityA, cityB, cityC]` I should get the same output as `[cityC,cityA,cityB]` and etc

Thank you

**EDIT**

I managed to do the second part by adding a dummy node, reference: [What TSP variant doesn't return to start point?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/43549/what-tsp-variant-doesnt-return-to-start-point)
So that the matrix would look like this?

```
[[0,9,0.6,10,10]
[9,0,10,2,1]
[0.6,10,0,10,10]
[10,2,10,0,0.8]
[10,1,10,0.8,0]
[0,0,0,0,0]]
```

However I still cannot figure out how to make it so you can start anywhere, thank you!

Comment: If you add the dummy node with 0 distance to all other nodes, then you've solved both issues.

Comment: (or really any constant distance; IIRC ant colony doesn't care about the instance satisfying the triangle inequality, but some TSP heuristics do)

Comment: Thanks guys, just to confirm if I am doing this right (because I think I might not), with my dummy node, should the final matrix, with input as ```cityA```, ```cityB```, ```cityC```, ```cityD```, ```cityE``` look like ```[[0,9,0.6,10,10]
[9,0,10,2,1]
[0.6,10,0,10,10]
[10,2,10,0,0.8]
[10,1,10,0.8,0]
[0,0,0,0,0]]```

Comment: For more clear representation check the matrix in EDIT  :)) thanks again!